# Date Picker for Angular that Ignores Local Timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

Is there any date picker that just displays what is supplied to it and ignores the local timezone?

We're currently using `angular-strap`'s date picker and the `data-min-date` changes when the local time zone of the computer is changed. The supplied `data-min-date` is just a fixed date but somehow the date picker is affected by the local time zone.

Example:

Supplied Date: `2016-12-23T16:33:03+08:00` `ISO8601 Format`

On `UTC-12:00` `22-December-2016` is disabled so the minimum is `23-December-2016`.

On `UTC+08:00` `23-December-2016` is disabled so the minimum is `24-December-2016`.

Not sure which one is the expected date, but the expected outcome should be that there will be no changes since a fixed date is supplied.

Is there anything I am missing or any other calendar that will just display what is given to it?

**EDIT 1**: Is it a legit way to test date functionalities  by changing the local timezone of a computer? Is it the same or different than when you are locally or naturally situated in that timezone?

**EDIT 2**: We already generated datetime from our `node server` using `momentjs`. `var serverTime = moment().utcOffset(8);` it's just the the `angular-strap` handles the date we supplied in an odd way.

**EDIT 3**: Adding an attribute `data-timezone="utc"` doesn't help either.

**EDIT 4**: We've discovered that the plug-in uses `date = new Date(value);` in which `value` is the date that we passed. And it returns something like `Thu Dec 22 2016 21:29:54 GMT-1200 (Local Standard Time)` which clearly uses the local timezone. And there is no condition to check if there is `timezone="utc"` supplied. We also tried to directly assign `date = Thu Dec 22 2016 21:29:54 GMT-1200 (Local Standard Time)` but the plug-in breaks.

Comment: Get today's date from server and set it as default date of datepicker control.

Comment: The thing is we are already generating time from the `node server` using `momentjs`. `var serverTime = moment().utcOffset(8);` it's just the the `angular-strap` handles the date we supplied in an odd way.

Comment: You want to select the local date/time in date picker or UTC?

Comment: Adding a `data-timezone="utc"` doesn't help either

Comment: But for the user at -12:00 it **is** December 22.

Comment: The goal of the application is have every user be referencing on the GMT+08 because the services are also based on that timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did a hack around. We forked the plug in and changed the code that handles the `min-date`.

Change history can be found [here](https://github.com/iamdevlinph/angular-strap/commit/009091b7a17c8e2cec1d017e66737e334c82c209). Snippet we added:

```
var a = new Date(value); // value - date we are passing
var b = a.getTime() + (a.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); // no idea what this is
date = new Date(b + (3600000*(8))); // the 8 is the timezone we want
```

The problem with the `new Date(value)` is that it is affected by the local timezone.